# Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, configuration, wampserver

I've just installed the latest version of WAMP on my dev machine, and I can't get it to work. Getting this weird error.

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin>httpd.exe
AH00526: Syntax error on line 224 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin>httpd.exe -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64)
Server built:   Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
```

This is the config at line 224:

```
222: <Directory />
223:    AllowOverride none
224:    Require all granted
225: </Directory>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `Require` directive is supplied by [mod_authz_core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html). If the module has not been compiled into your Apache binary, you will need to add an entry to your configuration file to load it manually. You can check which modules are compiled in with `httpd.exe -l`.

If the module is *not* compiled in, load it with a configuration line similar to the following:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module    "<apache install dir>/modules/standard/mod_authz_core.so"
```

You will need to adjust the path for your system of course, and on a Windows box the library may well be a `dll` rather than an `so` file.

Comment: The ```Order``` will require mod_access_compat too. To fix both of these run:
a2enmod authz_host
a2enmod access_compat
if these problem arise on linux and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @dannio, you fixed my problem. But can I just edit your command to `a2enmod authz_host access_compat`.