# WAMP won't start: Getting "AH00526: Syntax error on line 224 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf"

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, kohana-3.3

I am running into this problem where Wamp is Orange and wont start. I don't understand why this happened since everything was fine just a while ago. I was having trouble with a. framework (kohana) that I installed, then I resolved that issue by enabling " rewrite module" in apache everything work fine then. I don't know if the Apache's "orange issue" started right after that or later. Here are some errors that I see:

- In MySQL Log:

  > 2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
  >   2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
  >   disabled 2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks
  >   use Windows interlocked functions 2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276 [Note]
  >   InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276
  >   [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions 2014-04-16 12:02:03
  >   8276 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M 2014-04-16
  >   12:02:03 8276 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  >   2014-04-16 12:02:03 8276 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
  >   is Barracuda. 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback
  >   segment(s) are active. 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting
  >   for purge to start 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12
  >   started; log sequence number 2568346 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note]
  >   Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306 2014-04-16 12:02:04
  >   8276 [Note] IPv6 is available. 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] - '::'
  >   resolves to '::'; 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] Server socket
  >   created on IP: '::'. 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] Event Scheduler:
  >   Loaded 0 events 2014-04-16 12:02:04 8276 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for
  >   connections. Version: '5.6.12-log' socket: '' port: 3306 MySQL
  >   Community Server (GPL)

-In Windows Event Viewer:

```
> The Apache service named reported the following error:
> >>> Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration . The Apache service
> named reported the following error:
> >>> AH00526: Syntax error on line 224 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf: .
```

Not really sure why this is happening, and I am kinda of a new Wamp user, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The message is very clear... you have a syntax error on line 224 of your Apache config file, which has absolutely nothing to do with MySQL.  Go edit that file and see what the issue is.  If you can't figure it out, we would need to actually see that line and lines around it to help you.

Comment: Brad, Here is line 224: "Require all granted". Here it is with the lines around it beyond those there are a bunch of commented lines: <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 1):

My situation and how I fixed it:
-same syntax error
-same orange Wamp icon
- port 80 not used
- I had checked Windows "Event Viewer" (Start > search "Event Viewer") and verified the event with the syntax error from the OP's question.
- My windows is installed on the "E:" drive (that was a mistake), and WAMP is on 2nd hdd, "S:".
- I commented out some lines in this file: \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex using notepad
lines commented out like this:

```
# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If
# you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
#
#Alias /icons/ "s:/Apache24/icons/"
#
#<Directory "s:/Apache24/icons">
#    Options Indexes MultiViews
#    AllowOverride None
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Wamp works!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, there was an existing thread that I did not see :

[Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844338/invalid-command-require-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-include)

The Require directive is supplied by mod_authz_core. If the module has not been compiled into your Apache binary, you will need to add an entry to your configuration file to load it manually. You can check which modules are compiled in with httpd.exe -l.

If the module is not compiled in, load it with a configuration line similar to the following:

LoadModule authz_core_module    "/modules/standard/mod_authz_core.so"

You will need to adjust the path for your system of course, and on a Windows box the library may well be a dll rather than an so file.