# Get localhost running on mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, mysql, apache, osx-yosemite

I have updated my OS to Yosemite and the only issue I have is that my localhost is not working anymore. Please excuse if the questions sounds dumb but I have limited knowledge about servers.

with Mavericks I was able to use `localhost` and `customdomain.dev` right after a system start. Also my MySQL server has been started without any actions

Now Google Chrome throws an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when using localhost.

I run

```
apachectl configtest
```

which returns

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found
```

if I comment out this line it continues with other modules. When I comment out all modules which causes this syntax error I get

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 131 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'User', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I'm using the `httpd.conf` file from Mavericks (where everything worked fine)

I have no idea what I should do next

Comment: Not sure how to use `apachectl`, but I really like MAMP, the free version (http://www.mamp.info/en/). Excellent for running an Apache server locally.

Comment: I don't like to start an app every time I start my computer - it worked before so why not now?

Comment: Try backing up your `sites_available` folder and re-installing. Does the issue stay there?

Comment: @Qix sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: I get error apachectl configtest
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using buildserver.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you retain your original httpd.conf from before the upgrade? You may have to edit the modules in your httpd.conf

I found that an Apache upgrade came along with Yosemite. Apparently there are several authentication-related changes from Apache 2.2 to 2.4. I had to run `sudo apachectl configtest` repeatedly to display which modules to remove.

Then, I had to add some modules. My modules look like this now:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module libexec/apache2/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module libexec/apache2/mod_ident.so
LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

You'll see that I commented out a few. There are a few new ones. The two `_core_` ones, `unixd_module`, and `access_compat_module` are new. Don't mind the strange looking PHP module. That's from Homebrew's PHP.

I also had to remove the `LockFile` directive in `httpd-mpm.conf`. And the `NameVirtualHost` directive in `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I copied `/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf` to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and the server is working again. I have to re-configure that file for my need again but that wasn'T a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Regretted upgrading to Yosemite when this problem occured. 10 min later, problems fixed.
Blessed be the Overflow...

Comment: Thanks for this; I lost the will to live addressing this issue today. In the end, I also had to add: (1) `LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so` to deal with error message `Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844338/invalid-command-require-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-include (2) "Configuration File" section from http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/

Comment: Awesome--all I had to do is delete the php file!

Answer (score 1):

Since Mac OSX 10.10 `Yosemite` the `Web Sharing` option located previously in Settings -> Sharing ceased to exist, now manual configuration is necessary.

check this link:
http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/setup-local-web-server-apache-php-osx-yosemite.html

Answer (score 0):

Except [Stephen Farmers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4159875/stephen-farmer) very good answer. I also had to add one more module.

```
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
```

Otherwise apaches log was filled with messages like:

```
[proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 25593] AH01177: Failed to lookup provider 'shm' for 'slotmem': is mod_slotmem_shm loaded??
```

and it would not start.

Works fine now.

[Link to Apaches bugzilla report of this](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52841)

Comment: I think commenting out `proxy_balancer_module` fixed that for me. Not entirely sure. I wasn't using the load balancer on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this module seems to fix: Invalid command 'User'

```
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
```