# Upgrade to Yosemite - Apache config - Invalid command 'User'

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

I'm getting this when I upgrade to Yosemite:

```
$ apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 102 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'User', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

and on line 102:

```
User _www
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Turns out my conf file got blasted (again!).

This helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454160/get-localhost-running-on-mac-os-x-yosmite?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in apache httpd.conf (Default path : /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf)

```
LoadModule unixd_module  libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
```