# HTTPD restart error: Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module

Tags: php, apache, config, require

I upgraded PHP to 7.1.30 (Apache is at 2.4) and I'm getting this error upon restart:

```
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 26 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf:
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The Require in question looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Expecting HTTPD to start cleanly.

There is a similar question/answer on this site, but that is on Windows and refers to httpd.conf vs. autoindex.conf. I am on Linux:

Linux ip-10-149-85-249 4.14.121-85.96.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 22 00:45:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844338/invalid-command-require-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-include)